# Is it necessary for the Gym Leaders of a region to know each other?

Tags: pokemon

As far as I remember from the anime series and the games, after beating one of eight Gym Leaders in a region, some leader said something about the next Gym Leader.

Like they know who, where, or what specialist-type the next Gym Leader is.

But, I watched the current XY series, Clemont, the Gym Leader of Lumiose City's Gym who travels with Ash, always wonders about the kind of next Gym Leader that Ash will face.

**UPDATE**

Each region has 8 Gym Leaders, and they give a badge after being defeated. We need all 8 badges to enter the Pokemon League to beat the Elite Four and the Champion.

**I just want to know if they, as Gym Leaders, must have known each other or not?**

Comment: the question is far too broad to answer, it´s like you are asking do people know people. Some know each other some don´t.

Comment: @Eumel Yes I know, but I just want to know if them, as Gym Leaders, must know Each other or not, because they have same role that give trainer badge for access the league.

Comment: voting to reopen. it is not too broad, disagree with @Eumel. He is not asking if people know people. He is asking if **people belonging to a important and scpecific niche** know each other. Same question on a different setting: `Do all the Silicon Valley billion-dollar-companies CEOs know each other`? Hard to answer, but not too broad.

Comment: I can give this question a proper answer as-is as of the time of this comment posting.

Comment: I edited my question...

Comment: My closest guess would be comparing it to someone in the same business.  Theres 300+ people working in the same office as me, 3k or so in the same company all across the globe, but I only interact with 20 or so people.  I know of the highers ups and may recognize other team leaders or the CEO, but I haven't really spoken with them nor do i know fully what they do.  Maybe it's the same for Gym leaders, it's clearly an organization set up all over the world, and whilst you would expect the leaders in the same region to know each other, maybe Clemont put in no effort at all.

Comment: @gorp I would make that an answer since it' pretty much what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No there is no reason to. As some of the strongest trainers of the region, gym leaders may know each other but there is no necessity.**

Case in point, Misty didn't know Brock was Petalburg's gym leader even though she was at that time not the Cerulean's leader. But throughout the journey Brock doesn't recognise most of the gym leaders. On the other hand several leaders know each other as well as the Elite Four. The reason for this is probably gyms are taken over strong trainers who went to the league or the Elite Four.

The reason why this is not a necessity that there is no set order for you to fight the gym leaders. There is no prescribed order to fight the gyms in an order. Even in the first generation games you could possibly battle Fuchsia, Celadon and Saffron gyms in different orders. In future games the HMs can only be used by defeating a gym and that HM is usually required to reach that next gym and thus the need of order of a particular gym. Or sometimes its locked, gym leader missing etc. other side quests.

In the anime, the current gym leader would realistically know which gym is the closest and leaders are usually helpful enough to pass it on to the trainer. But he is not required to fight the gym and may chose to proceed to another. Example: Ash *skipped the Petalburg gym* because Vigoroth was too powerful for his team and came back later. (As I remember, been a long time since I last saw Pokemon)

Also it is conclusive there are *more* than 8 gyms in any region of pokemon.
Refer to: 
[Does each Region only have 8 gyms in pokemon?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/35645/does-each-region-only-have-8-gyms-in-pokemon/35652#35652)

Answer (score 0):

You mention both the games and the anime. Well, the answer depends on the canon referred to.

The *Pokemon Adventures* manga depicts how the Pokemon League is organized more clearly. The League sponsors gym leaders to run their gyms, challenge trainers, and give out badges. They are occasionally called together for meetings. In the manga we see the gym leaders gather together on several occasions. For instance, in the Gold and Silver chapter, there are a set of exhibition matches between the Johto and Kanto gym leaders. And since the gym leaders are considered the elites, they are often called upon when calamity strikes. Basically, the gym leaders are all part of the same organization and are likely to know each other.

Contrast this to the anime, where how the gym leaders and Pokemon League are organized is less clear. From observation of the gym leaders, it seems there is little reason for them to know each other. If they're not hanging with Ash or on a training journey in the next town, they mostly just seem to stay in one place. So then, we get gym leaders like Clemont who only have heard rumors about other gym leaders. Of course, post-XYZ, Clemont will have met all of the other gym leaders of Kalos.